# Doubts in Servlet works

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

We have an existing application where servlets has been loaded with URL (mentioned below) and they had not defined in web.xml.

**domain:9080/Smart/servlet/com.wm.FacXmlServlet**

Here FacXmlServlet class placed inside com.wm package.

Is it possible to do as per servlet rule where we defining that in web.xml servlet tag ?

Comment: you don't have to define in the web.xml. Nowadays you can also declare a servlet using annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the package in `web.xml`,which means `com.package.Test` Servlet class has been mapped to `/go/test` url or you can just annotate your class 
`@WebServlet("/path/MyServlet")` and that's it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.package.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/go/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But my project are legacy and not used any annotation. still its working as i mentioned above.